# I can't see Visio in the start menu after installing it in MS Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

If I start the office 2013 installation, it looks like Visio is installed, yet I don't see it listed in the start menu

[image]

Comment: It appears you have the Vizio **Viewer**, not the complete Vizio application. As such, it will open a Vizio file to view, but the file cannot be edited, so there is not much point in adding a shortcut to the menu. Just double-click a .vdx, .vsx, or .vtx file.

Comment: It's Visio, not Vizio.

Comment: @PaulHerber can you write "@" to the person you are addressing e.g. `@DrMoishe`  otherwise it looks like you are addressing me, and you are not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you installed the Visio viewer, which does not have a standalone application.  You can view Visio files from within Internet Explorer.

> [Download Microsoft Visio 2013 Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35811)
>
> Microsoft Visio 2013 Viewer allows anyone to view Visio drawings
>   inside their Microsoft Internet Explorer Web browser.

Comment: do you know if any office version includes full ms visio?

Comment: While technically part of Microsoft Office, Microsoft Visio (and Microsoft Project) are separately purchased programs.